# How to use jQuery to search for text that contains a bracket "("?

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use jQuery to locate all `<a>` tags that contain a piece of text in brackets so I can perform some manipulation on them. 
However I'm struggling to even find these tags. And I am getting a javascript error:

`"Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '(')"`

When  I try to use the following code:

`jQuery("a:contains(' (')").css("text-decoration", "underline");`

Presumably because the javascript doesn't like a ( within the contains function. Does anyone know a way around this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function(index){
    if($(this).text().indexOf('(')!=-1){
       $(this).css("text-decoration","underline");
    }
});
```

This is not a performant solution but just a hint, iterate over every `<a>` get their `text()` and if they contain a `(` underline them.

If your `(` is not in between `<a href="#"> HERE() </a>` you could check for the `href` attribute and get it's `value` and look if in the value it contains `(`

Answer (score 1):

Please check this

```
<script>
var sent = "(";
$("a:contains("+sent+")").css("text-decoration", "underline");
</script>
```